# At Night or In the Night?

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions

Why do we refer to morning, afternoon and evening as 'in the morning', 'in the afternoon', 'in the evening' but not 'in the night' instead we say 'at night.'

Comment: You can say "in the night" (meaning "during the night"), I think more usually referring to the past: *Did you hear that dog barking in the night?* At other times, you use "at" for a 'specific' time (*at midday; at 3 o'clock; at sunrise*), and "in" for a *period* of time.

Comment: @TrevorD Counterexample to the idea of referring to the past: speaking of things that go "bump" in the night.

Comment: *In the night* and *at night* do not mean quite the same thing.

Comment: "The curious case of the dog in the night[time]"

Comment: I keep coming across "'at night' is a short form for 'in the time of night' or 'in night-time'." Some ESL forums that I've perused were using this example. "I go to sleep in night-time." vs "I go to sleep at night." Could this possibly be of any use in this context?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHuko5BCFzA

Comment: Hi Fumble - it has no relation at all to idiom. It's no different that a "countable versus noncountable" issue.  You are 'in' an extent, but 'at' a point (applies both temporally and spatially).

Comment: Kris -- "In the night and at night do not mean quite the same thing. "  They mean utterly different things.  Note, it is exceedingly common in English that words have more than one meaning.  Notice in a dictionary all the many meanings of a word are given.  "I have two Labradoodles" (dogs)   "I created Labradoodles" (the breed).  So what?  Of course the two examples you give mean totally different things.

Comment: There are [plenty of instances of *at (the) morning*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+morn%2C+at+morning%2C+at+the+morn%2C+at+the+morning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20morn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20morn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20morning%3B%2Cc0) to be had.

Comment: that's not a counter example at all.  "things that go "bump" in the night" means precisely things that go "bump" in the night - during the night - exactly as TrevorD explains.

Comment: You may use your answer to correct the OP's statements, but please do not edit the question to change the OP's premise.

Answer (score 25):

The bottom line is "it's idiomatic" as mentioned but I can offer the below rationale:

**1.** ***The origin of "at night" to indicate a point of time and the usage of prepositions "in" and"at"***

In olden times, when the time expression "at night" was originated, *night* might have been thought as a point of time in the day because there wasn't any activity going on and people were sleeping that time unlike daytime. It represents the dark hours and the late time of the day. But *morning, afternoon and evening* represent a period of time during the daytime where activities were going on.

In fact, *night* is a period like *morning*. This is the main reason of the question because the preposition *in* is used for time periods. Then, the question can be easily changed to "why not *at morning* but *in the morning*" because it seems like times within the day generally take *at* (*at noon, at 5:00, at dawn, at dinner, at night*), except the ones that take *in* with the definite article *the* (*in the morning, in the evening, in the afternoon*).

Speaking exceptions, one grammar book says the below for *at* under the title "exceptions: *at, on* and *by*":

> ***At*** can be used for periods identified vaguely, as in a*t that time, at breakfast time, at night*; also for short holiday periods (*at Christmas, at Easter*). In BrE, *at the weekend* is used, but in AmE *on the weekend*.
>
> <sub>*A Communicative Grammar of English* By Geoffrey Leech, Jan Svartvik</sub>

In the end, *at* and *in* share a long history for the usages that we talk about and it is mentioned as below in *OED* (including the earliest example and some relevant examples):

> **at, prep.**
>    **IV.** Of time, order, occasion, cause, object.
>    **29.** Introducing the time at which an event happens:
>   **a.** with the time named.
>
> - c1230  (▸?a1200)      *Ancrene Riwle* (Corpus Cambr.) (1962) 28   Ed al le þe oþre tiden.
> - 1586     T. Bright *Treat. Melancholie* xviii. 114   From 3. at after noone till nine **at night.**
> - a1616     Shakespeare *Cymbeline* (1623) i. iii. 32   At the sixt houre **of Morne, at Noone, at Midnight.**
>
> ---
>
> **in, prep.** 
>   **III.** Of time. 
>    **18.**
>    **a.** Within the limits of a period or space of time.
>   <sub>With *in the day, in the night*: cf. *by day, by night* at by *prep.* 19b.</sub>
>
> - a900     *Anglo-Saxon Chron.* ann. 709   In foreweardum Danieles dagum.
> - 13..     *K. Alis.* 85   By cler candel, **in the nyght.**
> - a1616     Shakespeare *Two Gentlemen of Verona* (1623) iii. i. 178   Except I be by Siluia **in the night**..Vnlesse I looke on Siluia **in the day**.

**2.** ***Chaucer's influence on English and vernacular literature***

One of the earliest usages of "at night" is from *Chaucer*'s works. However, there is one earlier usage listed in *OED*. The following are the definition of *at night* and earliest examples from *OED*:

> **at night:** at nightfall, in the evening or night; during the hours of darkness. Freq. designating a specified time.
>
> - c1300     *St. Theophilus* (Laud) 161 in C. Horstmann *Early S.-Eng. Legendary* (1887) 293 *(MED)*,   Þis cas bi-feol in leinte on a satures-day **at niȝt**.
> - ▸c1387–95     Chaucer *Canterbury Tales Prol.* 23   **At nyght** was come..Wel nyne and twenty in a compaignye.

It seems like *Chaucer* might have a big role for the common usage of this idiomatic expression and the usage of this expression has been continued by other influential people like *Shakespeare* (example from *OED*):

> a1616     Shakespeare *Macbeth* (1623) iii. i. 43   Let euery man be master of his time Till seuen **at Night**.

---

Additionally, the expression *in the night* has a long history as well and *OED* lists as below: (including the earliest example and some relevant examples)

> **b.** **in (also †of, †on, †upon) the night** : by night, during the night.
>
> - OE     *Old Eng. Hexateuch: Exod.* (Claud.) xii. 12   Ic fare **on ðære nihte** ofer eall Egypta land.
> - a1400  (▸a1325)      *Cursor Mundi* (Vesp.) 6196   Drightin self þam ledd þair wai... Wit firen piler **on þe night** [c1460 Laud **vpon the nyȝt**].
> - c1480  (▸a1400)      *St. Theodora* 288 in W. M. Metcalfe *Legends Saints Sc. Dial.* (1896)   II. 107   To þat thing has he na sycht þat thocht or don is **in þe nycht**.
> - 1600     Shakespeare *Midsummer Night's Dream* ii. i. 253   There sleepes Tytania, sometime **of the night**.
> - 1990     *N.Y. Mag.* 30 Apr. 52/1   A dog howling **in the night**.

On the other hand, there are instances of  *at morning, at evening* and *at afternoon* but they are uncommon and literary mainly. (See: [Ngram result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20morning%2C%20at%20evening%2C%20at%20afternoon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20evening%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20afternoon%3B%2Cc0))

*OED* mentions the below adverbial phrases with modifying preposition (without article) for *morning*:

> **at (also †in, †on, before, till, etc.) morning , from morning till evening, from morning to night,** etc. Also with adjective, as **all (also each, every, next, etc.) morning.** Cf. a-morning *adv.*

There are examples with *at morning* and *at evening* and the earliest usage mentioned is *in morning*. The below are first three earliest usages and some relevant examples from *OED*:

> - a1400  (▸a1325)      *Cursor Mundi* (Vesp.) 7181   On nighter-tale, or **in morning.**
> - c1400  (▸?a1387)      Langland *Piers Plowman* (Huntington HM 137) (1873) C. xiv. 147 (MED),   Maules drowen hem to maules **on morwenynge** by hem-self, And femeles to femeles.
> - c1475  (▸a1449)      Lydgate *Testament* (Harl. 218) 286 in *Minor Poems* (1911) i. 340   Thamerous foules with motytes and carolles, Salue this sesoun **euery morwenyng**.
> - 1679     *Processes Kirkcudbright Sheriff Court* No. 282   Otherwayes no master that hath ane servant **at night** is sure to have them **at morning**.
> - 1849     M. Arnold *New Sirens* i,   I, who in your train **at morning** Stroll'd and sang with joyful mind, Heard, **at evening**, sounds of warning.
> - 1968     D. Moraes *My Son's Father* i. 3   **At morning** the sea was a very pale, indolent colour.

---

Finally, I'm including the below explanation from a linguistics standpoint (from the book *Cognitive and Communicative Approaches to Linguistic Analysis* edited by Ellen Contini-Morava, Robert S. Kirsner, Betsy Rodriguez-Bachiller). In summary, *night* is an exception and is shrunk to a point as a contrastive location in time in the phrase *at night* and the difference between *at night* and *in the night* is explained with examples.

> ***At* for temporal messages**
>
> ...*at*, designating a point in space, is used for point in time as well:
>
> > (37) He arrived *at three o'clock; at noon; at midnight; at sunset; at dawn*.
>
> Just as a spatial point has no length, depth, or height, a temporal point such as *three o'clock* and *noon*, has no duration. A problematic use of at is the phrase at night. Unlike noon, night lasts from eight to twelve hours. Section 3 showed that a three-dimensional location is sometimes shrunk to a point when the message is one of contrastive location. At *night* is the temporal analog of *at Plattsburgh* and *at Stoneybrook*, contrastive location in time:
>
> > (38) What do the pretty SMU girls like on their plates?
> >              "Pretty much hamburger, hotdogs, steak and, *at night*, maybe pizza"   Brown, 70361
>
> The contrast in (38) is the different food preferences of the girls at the noon and evening meals. The implication of contrast in *at night* is better perceived when compared to *in the night*. Suppose the song 'Strangers in the Night' were titles 'Strangers at night'. The title would no longer suggest two lonely people searching each other out, but  a dysfunctional couple: "Companions by Day, Strangers at Night".
>
> In example (39), the two phrases appear in a single passage. The neighbor of a woman who may or may not have committed suicide describes the circumstances of her death:
>
> > (39) I had made a habit of calling her *at night*, from my cottage, just to check. The last night I had called, but the line as always busy and it reassured me...
> >         She was found the day after at the bottom of the cliff. I tried to believe that what must have happened was that, restless, disturbed by this telephone call or whatever, she walked out *in the night*, as she had a habit of doing...With all that warm rain an the fog it might have been as simple as a loosened rock, a misstep.   Brown,1171886
>
> The phrase at night implies 'evenings rather than daytime' for the regular calls, a message of temporal contrast. *In the night* carries no hint of contrast; it describes the dark three-dimensional space into which the woman walked.

Comment: But, um, there actually **are** [instances of the morning versions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+morn%2C+at+morning%2C+at+the+morn%2C+at+the+morning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20morn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20morn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20morning%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @ermanen You might do so, yes. It used to be much more common.

Answer (score 7):

There is an element of idiomatic nuance at play here.
"I always brush my teeth at night," describes a mundane event that takes place every evening.
"Someone stole my new orchid in the night," has an appropriate and slightly sinister connotation and suggest the event took place during a specific night, ***the*** night.
Contrast the previous theft with the following, "Police report that car thefts are on the rise, particularly at night."  It describes an on-going nocturnal event.

Comment: Your theory is convincing, but "I always brush my teeth at morning/afternoon" does not sound right, even if the person brushes regularly.

Comment: @Asa: Normally, "I always brush my teeth in the morning/in the afternoon* is the idiomatic expression. *At morning/afternoon* is never heard in spoken (or even written) conversation. If one must use *at*, then *at dawn/midday/noon* would be more likely. However, those phrases refer to more specific times of day than *morning/afternoon*.

Comment: *at night* generally references things every night, because otherwise *tonight* would be used. It's the same as the difference between *in the morning* and *this morning*.

Comment: Note that we can habituate other parts of the day by pluralizing: _In the mornings/afternoons/evenings I used to sit on the balcony_. But not so much _night_, because _at night_ already habituates it, which is why _in the night_ has a specific rather than generic sense, and why **In the nights I used to sit on the balcony* sounds so strange.

Comment: I feel (no offence) this answer does no more than restate the question.  As Fumble precisely says in his Bounty Offering, **"I know the bottom line is "it's idiomatic", but there must be some rationale."**

Comment: (TBC, the whole trivial issue has no connection at all, whatsoever, in any way, to idiomatic issues -- I'm just saying that your answer here merely restates what Fumble says.)

Comment: Night is simply different from morning, afternoon, etc. Night is half our life; the time when we sleep, dream, and perform secret activities. It's ***special*** and it gets special treatment. It's also ***scary***, and gets even more special treatment for that reason.

Comment: John, it's not different in any way, whatsoever, from any of those things. The situation is incredibly simple.  There are "event" time concepts (such as "November 1"). And there are "extent" time concepts (such as  "Summer").  In English you can only use certain grammatical forms ("during" "when" "in" etc etc) with each. **This is as utterly commonplace as the difference between countable and uncountable concepts in English (the liquids versus items distinction).**  It's one of the first things you teach English learners.  It's **profoundly bizarre this whole question** got more than a glance.

Comment: {Of the many meanings of "Night", it happens to have meanings in both the "event" and "extent" camp -- again this is utterly, utterly unremarkable. Indeed looking at the uncountable/uncountableduality  example, there are far more words that have sense in both camps than the few words that only have a sense in one or the other camp.  Again it's utterly utterly unremarkable that "morning" is only one of the two camps.}

Answer (score 2):

Both *at night* and *in the night* are acceptable, though they have slightly different moods. There is no conclusive etymological evidence that I could find, though [etymonline suggests](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=at):

> In choosing between at church, in church, etc. at is properly distinguished from in or on by involving some practical connection; a worshipper is at church; a tourist is in the church.

Following this, it would be logical to claim that something *at night* is more connected to the time of day than something *in the night*. Curiously, our usage of *in the night* tends to be more connected to the noun; e.g. "thief in the night", "things that go bump in the night". These examples make little sense when apart from the night, however, they are quite poetic.

[Google's account of their usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+night%2Cin+the+night&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20night%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20night%3B%2Cc0) shows that the first written instances (that they have record of after 1500) of *at night* are some 50 years before the first *in the night*. The *in the night* was heavily favoured by poets, initially Shakespeare, and could have been constructed for its rhythm.

In conclusion, I could find no evidence explaining why "in the morning/afternoon/evening" evolved, but "at night" remained in its original form. This is obviously not a definitive answer, but I post it so that others may pick up where I left off.

Comment: Wow the article quoted is utterly appalling.  Look at the quoted sentence!  "There's some, uh, 'practical difference' but we don't know what it is." Imagine having the audacity to write on English and not knowing the difference between points and extents.  In a box, on a floor .. uh there's some 'practical difference' but we can't put our finger on it just now  ;-)

Comment: [These are interesting](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+morn%2C+at+morning%2C+at+the+morn%2C+at+the+morning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20morn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20morn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20morning%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: In English time related concepts can be either "events" or "extents".  (It's not unlike the countable-discrete/uncountable-volumetric difference for nouns.)  You use one or the other form depending on which it is.  (Some - most? - words can be used both ways; "night" has two different meanings, (a) "the event" it happened last night and (b) "the extent" 2am is during the night.  That's all there is to it: In English time related concepts can be either "events" or "extents".  So that's cleared up.

Comment: @JoeBlow: nope. "I sleep *at night*." vs "I sleep *at January 1*." What is the non-night corollary for "I sleep at..."?

Comment: I'm sorry, of course I meant "at night". So the question remains "in the night" vs "at night".  I'll delete my previous comment. Joe there's really no need to reply, besides my comment was directed at tchrist. I've read your many many responses. However, I am, as always, still very interested in the answers being posted.

Comment: Hi Ian McD.  "nope" what?  What do you mean by "non night corollary"?  In English there are two types of temporal concepts -- event, and span.  In your example both examples are "event" type.  Further on that, In the first instance you're referring to s **category** and in the second instance a **specific**.  So they have different verb forms and other joiners.  This is utterly commonplace in English.  {Indeed, exactly as in the duality "discrete-volumetric", by no means is there one exact set that is totally interchangeable within each group.  So what? You may as well ask why all...

Comment: ...verbs are not identically structured uniformly in English.}  Again, this question stuns me as a non-question.  the idea of event versus span time words in English is just so basic.  the whole QA is **profoundly weird**.  It's sort of freaking me out.

Answer (score 2):

Effective communication sometimes relies heavily on idiom. On that note, I agree with Michael Owen Sartin's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121864/2705).

The day is often divided into morning, afternoon and evening, and it is idiomatic to corresponding adverbial phrases of time as *in the morning/afternoon/evening*, either when referring to habitual occurrences or those that are imminent. For example:

> - I usually have coffee in the morning.
> - We meet in the evening.
> - She's coming in the afternoon.
> - "When are you going running tomorrow?" "In the morning."

In regular conversation, other modifiers or indicators (pronouns, etc) are used with *morning/afternoon/evening*. Sometimes, native speakers drop the articles and prepositions where nonessential to the understanding of the intended recipient. A few quick examples include: *tomorrow afternoon, this evening, yesterday morning, morning*, etc.

*In the night* is more formal and poetic, and thus rarely used in regular conversation, at least in my experience. However, it could be used in the same sense as the phrases *in the morning*, etc. On the other hand, *every night* is a phrase that is heard very often.

The phrase *at night* tends to be more common in reported speech and other expressions of habit (*... sleep at night* is a notable example). Equivalent expressions for other times of day are *at dawn/daybreak, at midday/noon, at dusk/twilight*. Of these, *at noon* probably occurs most frequently in spoken conversation.

Comment: You know, idiom is utterly unrelated here.  If you're using a point time, you say at .. at daybreak, at night, at easter, when lunch arrives.  if you're using a time period you say in .. in November, in the night, in Summer.

Comment: By *idiom* I'm referring to how language is used by its regular speakers, and that from a rather descriptive standpoint. Rules sometimes are inferred from patterns of speech. Both *morning* and *night* are periods of time, and the constructions *at morning* and *at night* are not ungrammatical, but the first you'd be hard-pressed to hear in common speech. *Red Sky at Morning* is the title of a couple books/films, so that construction is more literary than colloquial. I'm not sure I follow your argument.

Comment: Hi Jimi !  the answer to the question 'in' versus 'at' could not be simpler. It's just due to a point versus an extent.  Exactly like countable versus noncountable.  If someone asked "Why do we say *some* milk but we can't say *many* milk" the answer is just "look up countable in an ESL book".  It couldn't be simpler. (Idiom, like "see ya mate" is utterly unrelated to the issue.)

Comment: "Both morning and night are periods of time"  **Well no**, "morning" is a duration of time (like "January") and **is not** a point-time (like "January 1").  "night" is a duration of time (like "January") and **is** a point time (like "January 1").  So you can say "in" (or "during" etc) morning, January, night.  And you can say "at" (or "when arrives" etc) January 1, daybreak, night.

Comment: But that's precisely and exactly like asking "why does dog mean dog, and not cat".  Or, "why can dog mean 'dog breed' as well as 'dog', but 'cow' only means 'cow' and not 'cow breed'?  Who cares?

Comment: "It ("the afternoon") occurs at a specific moment after midday (noon), to be precise one second past."  no, that's totally wrong.  "the afternoon" is the period from (say) 1pm until (about) 5pm.  "the afternoon" is an EXTENT, exactly like saying, example, "November".  hence you say "in the afternoon" or "in november"

Comment: ("to be precise one second past" that;s when it **starts**.  in english "the afternoon" is a time extent, like "November" or "Summer")

Comment: "However, you could say: "We went shopping at night""  Well yes - I don't know how many times the obvious can be repeated.   Words often have two meanings in English.  "night" can mean the extent (like November) or it can mean the instant (like "November 3"").

Comment: (Note that an "instant", a "singular event" can of course (indeed always) has length, it's not a planck unit.  All "events" (aka "instants") are some length.  Summer is three months, November 1st is 24 hours, (or "7 hours" if you mean the business day) "night" is about 7 hours (however "night" in the sense of when you go out to dinner, "a night at the opera", is maybe 4 hours - that's, in English, a separate word spelled the same, we foolisgly don't have much of a word like soiree)

Answer (score 2):

As @tchrist comments, there are in fact plenty of written instances of [***at*** [the] morn/morning](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20morn%2C%20at%20morning%2C%20at%20the%20morn%2C%20at%20the%20morning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20morn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20morn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20morning%3B%2Cc0), but it's very much a declining/poetic usage.

Contrastingly, ***at*** [the] afternoon has never had any significant currency. Because ***afternoon*** already contains a [preposition of time/location](http://www.espressoenglish.net/prepositions-of-time-in-english/) *(**after**)*, adding another one *(**at**)* doesn't work.

---

And as @Joe Blow comments, ***in*** the morning/afternoon/night are common usages (where ***in*** is a [*container metaphor*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KBxT8RlfR4MC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=define%20%22container%20metaphor%22%20preposition&source=bl&ots=RRZLQLgQWX&sig=kgsm1gHn_wXIlG-IPRISkqCTyLo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lOgCVbOKMYPX7Abu2oBA&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=define%20%22container%20metaphor%22%20preposition&f=false) which invariably equates to a *duration* reference in temporal contexts). As opposed to the *locational metaphor* preposition ***at***, which in temporal contexts normally identifies a *specific point in time*.

Thus *"We will attack **at** night"* tends to imply ***at the point*** where day turns into night, whereas *"We will attack **in the** night"* implies ***any time during*** the night. But where the reference is to a "continuous, extended" activity *(I work **at/in the** night)*, both forms are used.

---

TL;DR: The issue isn't really *"Why do we use **at** for night, but **in the** for morning, evening?"*. It's *"Why **don't** we use **at** for morning, evening?"*. To which I suggest a major part of the answer is...

> ***Morning*** and **afternoon** are much more associated with (and influential towards) each other than they are to **night**. And **at** [the] **after**noon is awkward (because of the double preposition), which has led to **at** [the] morning falling out of favour "by association".

Answer (score 1):

It's because we are awake during the day, and asleep throughout most of the night.

Saying *in the morning/afternoon* means at any time within the period of morning or afternoon.

The same with *in the night*, if someone said that you would think of any time between the hours of 8pm and 6am, or thereabouts.

However, *at night* generally means the specific time between when night begins and when you go to sleep, let's say between 8pm and 10pm.

It's similar with other specific times of day, such as *at midnight* or *at noon*.

We also do it with the morning, but usually either say *at dawn* or *at the time I woke up* instead.

For example:

> I'm going out at night for a walk.

Generally people would say *tonight*, but for the basis of this question, saying this sentence would make one think the person is going out late (between 8pm and 10pm).

> I'm going out in the night for a walk.

This makes one think they are going out anytime between 8pm and 6am.

Comment: "I'm going out tonight" can  mean any time after 20.00 (8 PM) until the small hours e.g. 2 AM, especially if it's a club or discotheque. But if "I'm eating out tonight" it could be any time between 18.00 and 22.00 (generally speaking.) *"I'm going out in the night"* conjures someone going for a walk, alone, in the dark.

Comment: I like your answer, but I'm not sure those examples are idiomatic/colloquial. I'm not sure anyone (native/regular speaker) ever says *I'm going out at night*! *I'm going out in the night* is also not a construction that comes up in normal speech.

Comment: Hi Mari-Lou. "tonight" is a completely different word and sense from "night".

Comment: Mike, sleeping is utterly unrelated to the issue.  But other than that you're the only person who noted the (incredibly obvious) answer.  Good one.

Comment: @JoeBlow (Ahh! I see Mike has edited his answer). I realized later that I'd written *tonight* instead of *night*, but then I understood why I had written it that way, spontaneously without reflecting, because that's how English speaking people would normally say it. (1) *I'm going for a walk* ***tonight*** is more idiomatic.Compare: (2) *In the morning I'm going for a nice long walk* and (3) *At night I'm going for a nice long walk*. (3) is grammatical, but who says it? Why shouldn't we say: (4) *"In the night I'm going for a nice long walk"*? But we don't! Instead it's (1) i.e tonight.

Answer (score 0):

"night" can be used with several prepositions:

- at night, in/during the night, by night.

It is up to you which variant you use, the meaning is the same.

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/night

With periods of time you normally use "in" or "during". Sometimes dimensions are reduced. When you use "at" you either reduce a time stretch to a point of time or you have the concept of "at some point of the night". "by" is used in connection with light: by candlelight, by moonlight, by the first light of the day" and in analogy "by" can be used with day/night: Paris by night.

Answer (score -2):

> in that night

in a specified night

**e.g.** I saw a ghost while I was on the way going home in that night.

> in the night

in a specific time of the night only

**e.g.** I do my homework in the night before I go to sleep.

> at night

throughout the whole night

**e.g.** The night markets open at night only.

**e.g.** I sleep at night.

> in the morning

in a specific time of the morning only

**e.g.** I brush my teeth in the morning before I go to school/work.

> on the morning

in an unspecified specific morning

**e.g.** She called me on the morning of 1st June.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, oh, but this question doesn't ask about "on that night", so I'm excused from it. :P

Comment: Done adding "in the night" to my answer.

Comment: *"I do my homework in the night"* is perfectly fine without adding the: "before I go to sleep". Otherwise we'd say: *I do my homework before going to sleep* (It's shorter and means the same! :-)

Comment: By the way, can I ask that do you think my (whole) answer is correct or wrong?

Comment: If I want to say that I do my homework the _whole night_, I'd say "_I do my homework at night_" instead based on my answer.