# Afternoon OR in the afternoon

Tags: word-usage

Usually we say like : 
**I came in the morning, We are going in the evening, It happened at night etc**.

If something happens around 12.00 PM, then we can also say: **I had lunch at noon**.

But I have heard people say: **I am going in the afternoon**. Actually afternoon means some time after 12.00 PM. So why not "**I am going after noon**." ?

Hope you got my logic.

Comment: I'd say that 12:00 pm is used much less than 'noon' or 'midday' (and 12:00 am less than 'midnight') nowadays; it never made sense, and people found it hard to remember the convention.

Comment: related: [At Night or In the Night?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121858/at-night-or-in-the-night)

Comment: The noun _afternoon_ is not synonymous with the prepositional phrase _after noon_. Just look in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*After noon* is quite vague. Assuming the context of the 24-hour day, it could mean any time in the day after 12:00 pm, whether that means 12:30, 3:00, or 7:00.

EDIT: As Edwin Ashworth pointed out, informally, *after noon* probably means a short while after 12:00 pm, maybe within the hour. However, if Joe says "I'll pick you up after noon" without specifying the upper bound on the time, it's still a very vague phrase. I would avoid concluding anything from such an interaction without further clarification, unless you want to butt heads about semantics when Joe shows up at 3:00 and says "hey, I wasn't lying!"

*Afternoon* is a noun that is defined as a specific time period. ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/afternoon): The part of day from noon until dinnertime or sunset.) After *afternoon*, there is *evening*, and after that, there is *night*, both of which occur after 12:00 pm, but are separately defined time periods.

In essence, *afternoon* is *after noon*, but just because it is *after noon* does not mean it is *afternoon*.

Comment: In most informal circumstances, 'after noon' or more commonly 'after 12'  would be taken to mean 'not too long after 12 o'clock'.

Comment: Yeah, when I wrote my answer, I had in mind people like fathers working overtime, repairmen from questionable cable companies, and new lovers who promised to call, so you're right.