# What to call the time from "midnight to sunset"?

Tags: single-word-requests, time

In many religious calendars, the day goes from sunset to sunset.

When translating to the civil calendar, you can divide that day into two parts: from sunset to midnight (A), and from midnight to the following sunset (B).

For terminology, "eve" works well for part A.

Is there a term for part B?

The closest I've found are "day", "morning" and "morrow". Is there another term that could be used?

Comment: A similar question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69815/is-there-a-term-for-the-period-between-midnight-and-sunrise

Comment: Does it have to be from Old English, or can it be a loanword?  Some English speakers with exposure to Spanish, and **many** bilingual code-switchers use [*madrugada*](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=madrugada) for that purpose, as its meaning is exactly what you’re looking for and no other word serves: it’s the time between midnight and dawn.  (DRAE gives “Tiempo posterior a la medianoche y anterior al amanecer.”)

Comment: Also a Portuguese loanword: [The cock was standing by her side. “You,” she said to him, ”shall be appointed the watchman of the night. Your voice shall mark the watches of the night and shall warn the others that the *madrugada* comes.”](https://books.google.com/books?id=oJ0eAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA47&dq=%22madrugada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BnBHVanzHYLvtQX2-4Bg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBDg8#v=onepage&q=%22madrugada%22&f=false)

Comment: A loan word might be good...  But I'm looking for the time from midnight to the following sunset, in the evening.

Comment: If it was a work setting, I would call it a ***graveyard double shift***.

Comment: I gave the word "[postmidnight](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/244403/64985)" in the other question but it might be applied to your situation also. Let me know if it fits.

Comment: "Postmidnight" is interesting and could work, even though it doesn't really give the sense of the whole day until sunset.

Comment: Sunset to midnight is 'first sleep': [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4559/were-our-ancestors-segmented-sleepers) and [History.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/6171/how-many-hours-per-day-did-a-sumerian-farmer-sleep). I'd swear ELU also has one somewhere.

Comment: "morning" doesn't even come close. I don't understand your division, from midnight to sunset is currently more than 22 hours where I am. What is the purpose in dividing the day into a 22-hour part and a 3-hour part?

Comment: @ermanen: I would think it very strange to refer to, say, 9 PM  as "postmidnight".

Comment: @oerkelens: I was overlaying a 24 hour day starting at midnight with a ~24 hour day starting at sunset. Viewed from either perspective, the 'other' day is divided into two parts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a term in English that works.

For my computer code, I decided to call the two parts of the day simply "fragment 1" and "fragment 2." The term "fragment" does not imply how big it is.

Not very elegant, but that worked for my purposes.

Answer (score -1):

ante crespusculum? or ante opacare?   In the spirit of AM -- ante meridian?

Comment: A good answer to a single word request explains why the options presented work.

Comment: Hi Gianni, welcome to ELU.  Could you share the definition of those words, and where you found them?  That would greatly assist the OP in deciding which answer to choose.  Thanks!