# Is there an adjective synonyms with the expression "before dawn"?

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

Is there an adjective synonyms with the expression "before dawn" or "occurring before dawn"?

Comment: Dusk-twilight-night-midnight-twilight-dawn!

Comment: Related: [Is there a term for the period between midnight and sunrise?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/69815/191178)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a term for the period between midnight and sunrise?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69815/is-there-a-term-for-the-period-between-midnight-and-sunrise)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Predawn*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/predawn) is an adjective meaning *relating to or taking place before dawn* [Oxford]. For example, *the predawn noises woke him up*.